# Get leading alpha letters from string regex c# .net 4

Tags: c#, regex

Get leading alpha letters from string

Given strings like  "W6 8RF" or "WC2 5HS" how do you get the leading alphacharacters only

eG

```
Input       Wanted Result

"W6 8RF"    "W"

"WC2 5HS"   "WC"
```

My attempt

```
string result = Regex.Replace(postCode, @"^[A-Za-z]+", string.Empty);
```

Returns wrong results

Any suggestions

May Thanks

Comment: As simple as [**`^[A-Z]+`**](https://regex101.com/r/jO0tL0/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want to use `Regex.Match` rather than `Regex.Replace`, like so:

```
string result = Regex.Match(postCode, @"^[A-Za-z]+").Value;
```

Otherwise, your regex is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple task, you can use LINQ:

```
var s = "W6 8RF";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", s.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter)));
// => W
```

`TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter)` will take all the letters that are at the beginning of the string input, and `string.Join` will produce the final string.